# how to get the checkbox selected row values from Kendo Grid UI while pagination in MVC using Jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

how to get the checkbox selected row values from Kendo Grid UI while pagination in MVC using Jquery,

[checkbox selected row values from Kendo Grid UI while pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776716/in-kendo-grid-mulitiple-checkbox-selected-geting-only-one-value-at-jquery-readin/52646135#52646135)

I have followed the above link to get my work done,
I can able to get the current page selected row values, but am not able to get all the page selected row values.can you pls help me , how to get all the checkbox selected row values even pagination also. Ex: first page i'm selecting 2 row and the second page i'm selecting 2 row means when click of button 4 rows shoud get pass to the controller, pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it working using the PersistSelection functionality as in this demo: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/checkbox-selection

Than you can get the row values this way:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e){
    var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.selectedKeyNames().forEach(function (id) {
        console.log(grid.dataSource.get(id).ProductID);
    });
}
```